# function declaration for structured bindings

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

Can structured bindings only be used with some kind of "struct" as return value?

Give back any of class/struct e.g. a tuple here works fine:

```
auto f() 
{   
    return std::make_tuple(1,2.2);
}
```

Is there something which enables something like:

```
auto f() -> [int,double]
{
    return { 1, 2.2 }; //  maybe with or without braces arround
}
```

Comment: You can do `auto f() -> std::tuple<int,double>`.

Comment: Like Nathan said, any ad-hoc aggregate need is fulfilled since C++11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have a construct like

```
auto f() -> [int,double]
```

as there is no type information there.  The trailing return expects a *type-id* which is defined as a *type-specifier-seq abstract-declarator<sub>opt</sub>*

Since you have to specify a type in the return type you can use something like

```
auto f() -> std::tuple<int,double>
```

to specify you want to return a `int` and `double`.

Also note that [structured bindings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) can be used on classes with public data members, tuple like objects, and arrays.